# How can I return a set, array or anything of the inserted values after inserting values in a table in my postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql

I just want to return an array or set values(id and name) so that i can `console.log()` in my node.js application after the row has been inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_user(
    data json)
    RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare r_array text[];
begin
    insert into users(id, name, age, gender, mobile, email, password, time)
select 
    (data->>'id')::int,
    data->>'name',
    (data->>'age')::int,
    data->>'gender',
    (data->>'mobile')::bigint,
    data->>'email',
    data->>'password',
    data->>'time'
    returning
        users.id as r_id,
        users.name as r_name;
    insert into r_array values (r_id,r_name);
    return r_array;
end
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.create_user(json)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

My table where the rows are getting stored:

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    age integer NOT NULL,
    gender character varying(8) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    mobile bigint NOT NULL,
    email character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "time" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want the function to return the id and name values after they are stored in the table.

The function below only returns the name,i.e, a single value from the data inserted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_user(
    data json)
    RETURNS varchar
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare r_name varchar;
begin
    insert into users(id, name, age, gender, mobile, email, password, time)
select 
    (data->>'id')::int,
    data->>'name',
    (data->>'age')::int,
    data->>'gender',
    (data->>'mobile')::bigint,
    data->>'email',
    data->>'password',
    data->>'time'
    returning
        users.name into r_name;
    return r_name;
end
$BODY$;
```

Here is the sample json:

```
{"id":"230720","name":"Deep Mandal","age":"24","gender":"male","mobile":"916296866621","email":"deepmandal8747@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$b/H70deR75LC/Ij03O11RueaFTUJMyeelxH7c4F1MxB9LlmbSa28K","time":"2021-02-21T13:51:41.571Z"}
```

I want to return both id and name so that `console.log()` in my nodejs application.

I know my return statement is completely wrong in the first function. So any suggestions would do.

Comment: Post your table schema/some sample data and desired output

Comment: I have updated those details.

Comment: Share the sample JSON which you are trying to insert

Comment: You'll need to return a `record` or `(int, text)` tuple instead of a `text[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return more than value then you should use `RETURNS TABLE`. You can try below function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_user(
    data json)
    RETURNS table(id_ int, name_ varchar)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$

begin
return query
    insert into users(id, name, age, gender, mobile, email, password, time)
select 
    (data->>'id')::int,
    data->>'name',
    (data->>'age')::int,
    data->>'gender',
    (data->>'mobile')::bigint,
    data->>'email',
    data->>'password',
    data->>'time'
    returning
    users.id,
        users.name;
end
$BODY$;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=be633d7122b8b9f97ec51005d9082f60)

Comment: Works perfectly. Can u tell me more about the id_ and name_ naming conventions? Also how do you get an in depth knowledge about postgresql. I mean this language is too confusing. So can you refer me some resources that I can learn from?